# How to make div disappear when clicking outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the CSS & HTML for Wordpress

```
<style>
    .fixedmenu {
        background: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mixed-rounded-flat-icon/512/magnifier_glass-48.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 43px;
        height: 43px;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0px;
        top: 160px;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    .fixedmenu1 {
        background-color: #62bdb2;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100px;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0px;
        top: 160px;
        z-index: 1100;
        border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    }

    .fixedmenu_1 {
        margin: 0px 0 0 43px;
    }
</style>
<div class='fixedmenu' onClick='this.className=&apos;fixedmenu1&apos;'>
    <div class='fixedmenu_1'>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to make Wordpress search box disappear when outside of the div is clicked. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery you could do a little something like this. Click the red part of the box and the inner div will disappear.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xzc36bvc/2/

```
<div class='fixedmenu'>
  <div class='fixedmenu_1'></div>
</div>

$('.fixedmenu').on('click', function() {
    $('.fixedmenu_1').fadeOut(500);
})
```

Comment: Looks work in jsfiddle but I couldn't let it work in my computer. I copied the same code in jsfiddle.

Comment: Well you'll have to modify that code a bit to get it to work on your end. Inner will be the search box you want to hide, and the parent div will be the `outer` class. I'm assuming `fixedmenu` and `fixedmenu_1` are the divs that you are referring to, right?

Comment: Firstly, I wanted to use the same code to learn how it works on my computer and I created a "index.html" page. I put script, css and html codes exactly. Somehow, it didn't work. Could you upload an index.html file if you are available? It didn't work in my codes, as well.

Comment: You can totally use the same code. The only thing we add here is the jquery. Looking at the code you gave, it looks like `fixedmenu` is the div you want to click inside of. Let me edit the fiddle quick and let's see if that does it. Give the new fiddle a try.

Comment: Awesome and you're welcome! Could I maybe get an upvote for this? ;)

Comment: I guess because I am new member, I am not allowed to give upvote to you. Don't worry, I will give it ASAP.

Comment: Oh dang! No worries. I'm just glad it works for you =)